# Working AngularJS & Web api 2 port different problom

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have developed AngularJS application along with ASP.NET WebAPI 2, application structure should be website layer, data access layer (entity FW) , WebApi layer
every think works fine.

The problem is my website is running on `http://localhost:8080` and WebAPI runs on `http://localhost:1696/api/album`. Therefore I cannot access the data through angular service. I am looking for a permanent solution.

If I go for CORS is it a good solution ?

Comment: 1. You can use the IIS to serve the angular app and rewrite everything that doesn't contain "^/(api)" to "/"
2. Just enable CORS - it's the easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should do this with configuring CORS indeed by adding the configuration to either your WebAPI configuration or web.config.

For the WebAPI configuration you should specify the following:

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```

In the `web.config` it should look like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
<system.webServer>
```

Of course, this allows *all* origins, so you have to change it to `localhost:8080` in your situation. Keep in mind, different ports are different origins, so specifying only `localhost` isn't sufficient, the port should be added also!

When moving to production, you should configure the correct CORS locations via the build server of course, but that's a completely different topic.